# Linux task schedule to Hour, minute, second

Tags: linux, task, schedule, seconds

I'm trying to run a shell script at a specific time up to it's seconds (H:M:S) , but so far all programs such as `at` only go up to a specific minute (not second).
I don't want to use `sleep` since it's not accurate. For some reason it ended couple of hours earlier than it was supposed to!

Comment: Show us more details?

Comment: Sleeps can be interrupted, the pattern is `while (now < scheduled) sleep(scheduled - now);`

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't seem to define accuracy, but there is always some [jitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitter) in scheduling in electronic devices. You might use [quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) to schedule to the second. You could also use `at` or `cron` to schedule to the minute and then sleep the appropriate number of second(s).